# How to write PHP code to execute two functions

Tags: php, curl, docker, http-post

I have this PHP script (for the Docker remote API), which I'm using for stopping a container "remotely":

```
<?php

$cid = trim(file_get_contents('cid'));
echo "$cid\n";

function httpPost($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

$url = "http://172.17.0.1:2375/containers/$cid/stop?t=5";
echo "$url\n";
echo httpPost($url)

?>
```

It works!   But I would like to have this piece of code to "stop" **two** docker containers, instead of only one.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
$cid = trim(file_get_contents('cid'));
$pid = trim(file_get_contents('pid'));
```

Then how would the rest of the code look like, so that we stop both of them?

Answer (score 0):

Switch this part:

```
$url = "http://172.17.0.1:2375/containers/$cid/stop?t=5";
echo "$url\n";
echo httpPost($url)
```

To this

```
$url1 = "http://172.17.0.1:2375/containers/$cid/stop?t=5";
$url2 = "http://172.17.0.1:2375/containers/$pid/stop?t=5";

echo httpPost($url1);
echo httpPost($url2);
```

That's how you can do it **basicly**. There can create more complex structs.

Comment: Oh, ofcourse $pid = trim(file_get_contents('pid')); is required.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.  Perhaps because this line: `function httpPost($url)` and this one: `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);`  refer to the previous $url variable.   Should we edit these parts of the code too?

Comment: And yes, I also added `$pid = trim(file_get_contents('pid'));`

Comment: Nie.  That url variable just in function and function takes it via parameter.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors.  Only I realize that the script does nothing.

Comment: It should be noted that I'm calling this PHP script from a jQuery function...  (a simple button I have, that does the job).  The relavant part looks like this: `xhttp.open("POST", "button.php", true);`

Comment: Perhaps I should call the php script from command-line instead, so that I can debug what's happening?